# Check user logged in with JS

Tags: javascript, login, regex

I use FaceBook JS SDK to check whether the user has permission to log in to my site or not. If user has permission I log him into the WP site.

**It is possible to check with JS whether the user already logged in or not?** Possible to check existance of `wordpress_logged_in_` cookie, and how?

I am trying with this code, but doesn't work:

```
if (document.cookie.search(/^wordpress_logged_in_\w*/) >= 0) {
  // Cookei exsist.
  alert("Cookie");
}
```

thanks,

Answer (score 3):

Just use [`wp_localize_script()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script) and [`is_user_logged_in()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_user_logged_in).

```
wp_localize_script( 
    'my-ajax-request', 
    'MyAjax', 
    array( 
        'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
        'logged_in' => is_user_logged_in()
    ) 
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  logged = <?php if(is_user_logged_in()): echo 1 ; else: echo 0 ; endif; ?> ;
  if(!logged){
    // Execute Google Analytics Code Here
  }
</script>
```

A bit of PHP can make it a whole lot easier.
It will work in wordpress 2.0.0+

Comment: Still works now, nice solution!