# Check if user is logged in via JS?

Tags: users, login

Im experimenting with random theme and "new technology" and Im trying to convert whole front-end to pure JS single page application *(no page refreshes - like Facebook, Twitter etc)* using [WP REST API](http://wp-api.org/), [Redux.js](http://redux.js.org/) and [React.js](https://facebook.github.io/react/) and few other helpers.

**How to handle logged-in users?** How do I keep track of that? I know that this information is normally handled with cookies. How would one check it *via* JS?

I could just make an ajax call every time route/url changes and use `is_user_logged_in()` in server-side but it seems primative. Could I access directly to cookie *via* JS and check it in browser?

---

- I gave it a long thought if that's off-topic here but it really seems like a very WP specific question
- Im just experimenting and trying to push it to a new level, please no *"this is a bad idea"* comments

Comment: This seems on the fence. [`body_class()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/body_class) has `logged-in` class which you could check for in JS. I think the best bet is to check all these things on `init` ( or a similar hook ) and [localize them to your JS](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script)

Comment: @Howdy_McGee This is not going to work because whole DOM is generated _via_ JS/React.js. I could hard-code this class but it can be _hacked_. Im wondering if there's a more secure way..

Comment: Localization may be your best bet then.

Comment: There is also http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/50165/check-user-logged-in-with-js and probably more.

Comment: @toscho This is not a solution to my problem. `wp_localize_script()` only checks if user is logged in if page is (re)loaded and might be invalid at some point in single page app _(which doesn't require reloading)_. Im currently thinking if it's possible to: **1. Capture the session name if user logs in, is it possible?** **2.** Save it as user meta **3.** Fetch it and save it as JS variable **4.** Check if that session exists by name if needed _(which is possible in JS)_  - e.g with every url/route change. Why I would need to capture the name? Because name (also value) is randomly generated.

Comment: You still have to **validate** that information on the server side with PHP for security.

Comment: @toscho Yup, Im aware of that. I would validate it _via_ ajax if user action requires "more strict" security and use JS solution for minor things that doesn't require strict security. Regular ajax calls with every action user takes would slow the navigation down big time which would make this experiment pointless. You seem to have a lot of experience with WP _(over 5 years here alone)_, is there a way to capture session name when user logs in?

Comment: There is no _session_. There are authentication cookies. See `wp_set_auth_cookie()` for the names and hooks to capture these. You still have to pass the data to JavaScript per HTML – with something like `wp_localize_script()`. That's how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are going to send ajax request from theme (frontend) you need to specify the ajaxurl otherwise it will throw an error "undefined ajaurl"

```
/**
 * frontend ajax requests.
 */
wp_enqueue_script( 'frontend-ajax', JS_DIR_URI . 'frontend-ajax.js', array('jquery'), null, true );
wp_localize_script( 'frontend-ajax', 'frontend_ajax_object',
    array( 
        'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )
    )
);
```

then in your frontend-ajax.js you can can send ajax request like this

```
$.ajax({
    url: frontend_ajax_object.ajaxurl,
    type: 'GET',
    data: {
        action: 'register_action_hook',
    },
    success: function( response ) {
        console.log( response );
    },
});
```

then in your functions.php you can hook your function to the register_action_hook.

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_register_action_hook', 'prefix_do_something' );
function prefix_do_something() {
    if ( is_user_logged_in ) {
        // do something
    } else {
        // do something else
    }
}
```

you can also use the @Howdy_McGee method to localize the is_logged_in variable using

```
wp_localize_script( 'handler', 'js_object', $array_of_variables );
```

and accessing it in your js with js_object.variable_name see the @Howdy_McGee answer for reference.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to check cookies than (and probably DB) or call a function somehow (maybe ajax or something like that) to check if user is logged in and what user is it. Try looking at the function wp_validate_auth_cookie() at wp-includes/pluggable.php

Answer (score 0):

We can localize data whenever we enqueue the scripts:

```
function localize_vars() {

    // Register your script so we may reference it.
    wp_register_script( 'some_handle', 'path/to/myscript.js' );

    $js_arr = array( 'logged_in' => is_user_logged_in() );

    // Localize our data
    wp_localize_script( 'some_handle', 'object_name', $js_arr );

    // Enqueue Your Script!
    wp_enqueue_script( 'some_handle' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'localize_vars' );
```

We register our script, create an associative array so it can convert it to object properties, localize it, and finally enqueue it as normal. In your JS file you can then check if a user is logged in by referencing the `object_name` and associative array index:

```
jQuery( function( $ ) {
    if( object_name.logged_in ) { // True or False 
        /* ... */
    }
} );
```